# Generate fake answers for a math calculation

Tags: c#, math, random, unity-game-engine, calculator

I am making a quiz like game where I generate math expression and then I generate plus two fake answers given the result of the generated math expression. So user sees the math expression and is given three answers from which he need to choose the right one.

So far I have

```
switch(opIndexValue)
{
    case Helper.CASE_ADD:
        answer1 = resultValue + Random.Range(1, 4);
        answer2 = resultValue - Random.Range(1, 4);
        break;
    case Helper.CASE_SUBTR:
        answer1 = resultValue + Random.Range(1, 4);
        answer2 = resultValue - Random.Range(1, 4);
        break;
    case Helper.CASE_MULTI:
        answer1 = resultValue + Random.Range(1, 4);
        answer2 = resultValue - Random.Range(1, 4);
        break;
    case Helper.CASE_DIVIS:
        answer1 = resultValue + Random.Range(1, 4);
        answer2 = resultValue - Random.Range(1, 4);
        break;
}
```

It looks decent and it does the job but its kind of generic. 
If you are and adult it would be quite easy for you to distigush the right solution among the three even without calculating in your mind.

If you were a mathematician how would you generate the two fake answers?
On the other hand how would you generate 4 fake answers? :)

The code is written in C# / Unity3D 5.1.4.

Comment: Seems like you only deal with arithmetics and primitive operations. In this case i would implement a simple delegate called ArithmeticOperation which would take 2 arguments and add/multiply/... them. In the app I would use 1 correct ArithmeticOperation and choose another random ArithmeticOperation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has more to do with coming up with good quiz answers than with programming.

Comment: @Bart I disagree. Vlad, read about [C# Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)

Comment: Why do you want to make simple math problems multiple choice? Why not just 38 + 65 = _______?

Comment: Because pressing a button with right or wrong answer is faster than typing 1-2 letters in an input field :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue.

One possibility is to look for a solution others have created. For example, [Thinksy](https://www.thinksylearn.com/) made a Unity plugin that can request questions from their server as well as the correct answer and distracting incorrect answers suitable for multiple choice. When I last checked, their system was pretty rough and limited to K-2 questions, but eventually they might have something helpful.

I recommend making your own system for generating distracting wrong answers. You should not assume that all errors are just from adding a random small number to the answer. It is common to err by making errors in other digits (34+57 = 81), or by performing the wrong operation (5*6=11), or by using the wrong inputs (7^2=64). So, try picking an error type randomly, and then verify that you don't accidentally get the right answer (1/2 * 1/3 = 1/2 - 1/3) or a previously generated wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error in the approach in your question is that the median of the three possible answers is always the correct answer. I don't even need to know what the problem is: if the possible answers are

(a) 7
(b) 4
(c) 5

the answer must be (c) 5.

A better way to do this is to simulate how people typically do addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, etc. Addition of multi-digit numbers often involves moving from right to left, adding aligned digits, and "carrying 1's." Sometimes people make mistakes by forgetting to carry a 1, or by incorrectly adding a pair of single digits.

Here's an example. Let's say the problem is 38 + 65. I would solve the problem like this:

```
         1     11     11     <-- carried 1's
  38     38     38     38
+ 65   + 65   + 65   + 65
----   ----   ----   ----
          3     03    103
```

These were the individual operations I performed

(1) 8 + 5 => 13
(2) Carry 1
(3) 1 + 3 + 6 => 10
(4) Carry 1

What would be a good way to generate wrong answers to the problem that match common mistakes people make? Just inject errors into one of the 4 steps above.

For example, if I generated an incorrect answer by skipping step (2), I would get the answer 93.

Comment: You'll have to do this for every kind of supported operation though. And if the actual questions are composed of multiple operations, maybe even parentheses, you'll have even more fun work to do!